# radio button multiple selection

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have many radio buttons with different name attribute and I am facing one problem. Every time I click on each radio button, I can select all. I am using the radio buttons for redirecting to other pages.

**I don't want to have multiple selection just only one**. I am using twitter bootstrap tabs for showing multiple content on one page just by switching the tabs if that has something to do with the prob. Can someone help me out?

**php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['cleat']) && !empty($_POST['cleat'])) {

        header("location: sporting_goods");
        exit();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['cell']) && !empty($_POST['cell'])) {

        header("location: cellphones");
        exit();
    }

}
?>
```

**css**

```
 .radto{vertical-align:top;}
 .sell_ali{display:inline-block;}
```

**html**

```
 <form action="" method="post">
 <div class="tabbable tabs-left" style="margin-bottom: 18px;">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Electronics</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Sporting Goods</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-content" style="padding-bottom: 9px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
  <div class="sell-ali">
  <li><input type="radio" class="radto" name="camera"/>&nbsp;   &nbsp;Cameras</li>
  <li><input type="radio" class="radto" name="cell"/>&nbsp;   &nbsp;Cell Phones</li>
  <li><input type="radio" class="radto" name="cell_cover"/>&nbsp;   &nbsp;Cell Phone Covers</li>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
  <div class="sell-ali">
  <li><input type="radio" class="radto" name="ball">&nbsp; &nbsp;Balls</li>
  <li><input type="radio" class="radto" name="cleat">&nbsp; &nbsp;Cleats</li>
  <li><input type="radio" class="radto" name="jersey">&nbsp; &nbsp;Jersey</li>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="next" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You need to give them the same **name** so they'll be connected (The ID should be unique though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give then the same `name`. That is how you create a radio button group.

Use the `value` for the piece of data that the user is picking from that group.

Comment: how about the redirect part though? I thought it would work just with the value but it isn't. Isn't name attribute required for the form to be submited?

Comment: You test along the lines of  `$_POST['common_name'] == "foo"` instead of testing if  `$_POST['foo']` exists

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow just one choice you should give them same name buddy. then set the value you want to send to server for each one.